# MVC 5 Federated Authentication config 2 RP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, wif, federated-identity

I'm pretty new in the Identity Model. The situation is next.

I have 2 mvc 5.1 applications:

- localhost:50475  - STS
- localhost:50473  - RP (application which consumes identity claims)

In web.config of RP I've configured federation authentication to get claims from the STS

```
  <system.identityModel>
            <identityConfiguration>
                <audienceUris>
                    <add value="http://localhost:50473/" />
                </audienceUris>
                <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
                <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                    <trustedIssuers>
                        <add thumbprint="..." name="WSFederationSTS" />
                    </trustedIssuers>
                </issuerNameRegistry>
            </identityConfiguration>
        </system.identityModel>
        <system.identityModel.services>
            <federationConfiguration>
                <wsFederation
                    passiveRedirectEnabled="true"
                    issuer="http://localhost:50475/WSFederationSecurityTokenService.svc/Issue"
                    realm="http://localhost:50473/"
                    requireHttps="false" />
                    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
            </federationConfiguration>
        </system.identityModel.services>
```

And it work's fine.

Now I have another application which should works with the same STS. The Url is localhost:50474

So federation authentication configuration there is

```
<system.identityModel>
        <identityConfiguration>
            <audienceUris>
                <add value="http://localhost:50474/" />
            </audienceUris>
            <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
            <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <trustedIssuers>
                    <add thumbprint="..." name="WSFederationSTS" />
                </trustedIssuers>
            </issuerNameRegistry>
        </identityConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel>
    <system.identityModel.services>
        <federationConfiguration>
            <wsFederation
                passiveRedirectEnabled="true"
                issuer="http://localhost:50475/WSFederationSecurityTokenService.svc/Issue"
                realm="http://localhost:50474/"
                requireHttps="false" />
            <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
        </federationConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel.services>
```

But for the second application it doesn't work. When it starts, browser redirects request to STS, login is provided, but when browser is redirected to the application again, I get an error:

```
[SecurityTokenException: ID4243: Could not create a SecurityToken. A token was not found in the token cache and no cookie was found in the context.]
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +634156
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[] token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +76
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[] sessionCookie) +417
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken) +176
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +116
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

I see that request to the application after login in STS contains FedAuth cookie, but it seems that application doesn't recognize it. Why? Is my configuration wrong?

TNX

Comment: Still haven't found the reason. But the workaround

Comment: void Application_OnError()
        {
            var ex = Server.GetLastError();
            if (ex is SecurityTokenException)
                Context.ClearError();
            
        }

Comment: Irina, what was the workaround?